# Java Reflection Mechanism for dynamic parameter invocation

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, parameters

I am writing a program that will call functions from classes located JAR Files. To understand the nature of my question please follow the next example.

Assuming that I want to call a method performAction(User user) from a class. This will take as an argument an User object. The User class consists of a FullName field ( another class consisting of two java primitives : String surname and name) and an int age field.

Giving the above example, how can you call a method using Reflection by getting the type of the parameters **BEFORE** using method.invoke(). In order to use the invoke() function you need to know the type of the parameters. Is there any 'dynamic' way of obtaining parameters' type before calling the method.

Also, I am also interested in finding a recursive mechanism used to instantiate recursively objects, that will be then assed as arguments to the functions to be called. (e.g. instantiate an User object by creating first the FullName Object).

Is it supported? Are there any libraries for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc of `Method`? There is a `getParameterTypes` method.

Comment: I think you can call the getParameterTypes method after the getMethod function. Within the getMethod () you need to provide the type of the parameters of that method.

Comment: Don't use `getMethod`, use `getMethods`.

Comment: Check out [`Expression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Expression.html), maybe it helps.